# Computing number of squares between two numbers, works only with small numbers, why?

Tags: java

The problem is to find the numbers of squares between two numbers.

The code below works small numbers but fails for huge numbers. How can I correct this?

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.math.*;
 import java.util.regex.*;

 public class NumOfSqrs {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String input;
    int line = 0;
    int testCases;
    int numOfSqrt = 0;      
    int j = 0;  

    while((input=br.readLine())!=null){

        if(line == 0){
          testCases = Integer.parseInt(input);
          line = line +1;
        }
        else{
          String[] splitter = input.toString().split(" ");

          //Here splitter gives two numbers, we need to find no of sqrs b/w these numbers for eg say 3 and 9

           for(int i = Integer.parseInt(splitter[0]); i<=Integer.parseInt(splitter[1]) ; i++){

            String value = ""+Math.sqrt(i);
            String[] isSqrt = value.toString().split("\\.");
            //System.out.println(""+isSqrt[0] + "" + isSqrt[1]);

            //Here lets say if  'i' is 4 (i.e 2.0) then isSqrt[0] = 2, isSqrt[1] = 0 and if isSqrt[1] != 1 then its obvious that its not a perfect square

            if(isSqrt[1].length() == 1){
              numOfSqrt++;
            }

          }
          System.out.println(""+numOfSqrt);
        }
     numOfSqrt = 0;
    }


    }catch(IOException io){
        io.printStackTrace();
    }   


  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe codereview.stackexchange would be a better forum for this.

Comment: Can you please specify the maximum range for your program? Like numbers can be between 0 and 1,000,000? or exactly the biggest case you can get?

Comment: Can you also state whether you would like to have it run fast for a single case or over multiple queries? So is the important thing is to answer 3 10 and 1 10000 and 1 1000000 all in better time or you would rather optimize the the time for a single operation. So you want yo answer just the question for 1 query?

Comment: The range can be anywer between 1 to 10^9

Comment: @MikeSamuel codereview.stackexchange.com is about asking for improvements on working code. Help with finding bugs and solving known problems is on-topic for SO and off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: Can you give an example of a number it fails on?

Comment: @Lundin, Before edits, the OP was asking about ways to improve performance, so my understanding is the OP asserts the code is correct but not tractable.  If I'm right about that, is it still off-topic for SO?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your technique for determining squares (converting to String and splitting on dot) is dodgy.

It's also unnecessary - you can use purely numeric approach in just one line:

```
int low, high; // fill from input
int numOfSqrt = (int) (Math.floor(Math.sqrt(high)) - Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(low)) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler algorithm, and it works up to 100,000,000 relatively fast.

```
int low = 1, high = 100000000;
int max = 0;
int count = 0;

for (int j = low; j <= high; j++)
{
    while (max * max < j)
        max++;

    if (max * max == j)
        Console.WriteLine(max * max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to find the square root the first number given in the input ,let us take it as 10 and the  square root will be like 3.(some thing) now take 4 and check whether 16 is in the range and like that for 5 check whether 25 is in the range and so on.